# sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.7.0-SNAPSHOT: not found

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, apache-spark, intellij-plugin

this is my `build.sbt` file under `/sbt/0.13/plugins`

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.5"

sbtVersion := "0.13.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.2.1"

resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.7.0-SNAPSHOT")
```

I get

```
[info] Resolving com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.7.0-SNAPSHOT ...
[warn]  module not found: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.7.0-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/cloudera/.ivy2/local/com.github.mpeltonen/sbt-idea/scala_2.11/sbt_0.13/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.11_0.13/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT/sbt-idea-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.11_0.13/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT/sbt-idea-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.7.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.github.mpeltonen:sbt-idea:1.7.0-SNAPSHOT (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.11)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.github.mpeltonen:sbt-idea:1.7.0-SNAPSHOT (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.11) (/home/cloudera/.sbt/0.13/plugins/build.sbt#L13-14)
[warn]        +- default:plugins_2.11:0.1-SNAPSHOT
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.7.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:278)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:175)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:157)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:151)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:151)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:128)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:56)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:64)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:64)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:123)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:120)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:151)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:157)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1318)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1315)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$85.apply(Defaults.scala:1345)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$85.apply(Defaults.scala:1343)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1348)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1342)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1360)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1300)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1275)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.7.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

this occurs with both the stable sbt-idea 1.6 and the snapshot of the 1.7.
No idea why and this was working until yesterday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split this config into two parts.

In your  `.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt` just put the lines

```
resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.7.0-SNAPSHOT")
```

for the idea plugin.

Put the other lines in the build.sbt of your project.

The way you mix it you tell sbt to download a Scala 2.11 version of the plugin, which doesn't exist, and which you wouldn't want, as sbt itself was compiled with 2.10.